# Is it okay to use emojis in Logcat logs?

Tags: android, logcat, emoji

I am using emojis in log cat messages in order to make the logs easier on the eye. So far it works fine, but I wonder if I'll hit any character compatibility issues on older Android devices. My app's minimumSdkVersion is 16.

Examples:

```
companion object {
    private const val TAG = "\uD83D\uDD36SomeClass"
}

...    

Log.d(TAG, "⏰ Something happened!")
```

Is there anything I should be worried about? Are there any reasons against doing this?

Comment: there is an open google [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37047280) related to this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your emojis in Logcat but I think that if you want to make your life easier use the TAG that inside your `Log.d`.

**For example, here is a log with a custom TAG:**

```
   Log.d("myTag","something to show");
```

After you run your app all you need to do is to search the same tag name within your logcat, like this:

[image]

---

Another thing that you should think about that if you want to search for a specific log would it be comfortable to search the logcat using emojis?

In my opinion, simply searching your tag name to find your log makes thing super easy.

Comment: This is a good advice but it does not answer the question "Is there anything I should be worried about? Are there any reasons against doing this?"

Comment: I agree with your points, perhaps keeping them out of TAGs is a good idea. But since it's a personal project I don't really worry about them much.  What I am most concerned about are potential crashes, etc... basically any problems on other devices.

Comment: Just checked on android 6 and I don't think that this would be a problem, because when you have emoji + string in a log line, if your emoji is not supported the compiler will just consider as a string. Then again - what is your definition for old device?